# How to get Tags of Azure ResourceManagementClient object

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

I' m trying to get tag list of the resource groups with ResourceManagementClient class.

*'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources 2.14.1-preview'* is added from *Package Manager Console*

```
ResourceManagementClient resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(new Microsoft.Azure.CertificateCloudCredentials(SubscriptionId, cert));

var tags = resourceClient.Tags.List();
```

I get this error;
**AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is not present or provided in an invalid format.**

At another sample, the part is working below;

```
StorageManagementClient storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CertificateCloudCredentials(SubscriptionId, cert));
```

There is a difference between these code parts. **Microsoft.Azure** is used for first sample and **Microsoft.WindowsAzure** is used for second and the second sample is working.

How can I fix the problem at first sample, can you explain the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have strong belief that ResourceManagementClient can't work with CertificateCloudCredentials, at least that was true for [ARM Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx).
I guess you need to first authorize user with login/password as described [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/USING-ADAL-NET-TO-AUTHENTICATE-USERS-VIA-USERNAMEPASSWORD/) and then use obtained token with ResourceManagementClient

**Update:**
First link describes how to register application in AD- can be done from the portal.
Next you need to have register in AD a user who will be co-administrator for subscription.
After that obtain authorization token with code from second link (using login/password created on prev step)
An finally use that token for ResourceManagementClient authorization, something like this(does not compile):

```
var credentials = new TokenCloudCredentials(<subscrtiption id>, <token>);
new ResourceManagerClient(credentials).DoSomething();
```

Comment: Hi @horseman, we are developing automated application, user interaction must not be used. Do you know any alternative way?

Comment: We are doing the same, and you just need just to combine two links from my answer

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/11/25/unattended-authentication-to-azure-management-apis-with-azure-active-directory.aspx